# Dynamically create variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, variables

I cannot get this to work:

```
function formvalidation()
{
  var SiteNum= document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].value;           
  var i=1;
  while (i<=SiteNum)
  {
    var SitePhone= document.getElementsByName(site['i'])[0].value;  
    alert(SitePhone);
    i++;
  }
}
```

If I alert like so: `alert('document.getElementsByName(site["'+i+'"])[0].value');` it will display the following:

```
document.getElementsByName(site["1"])[0].value
document.getElementsByName(site["2"])[0].value
document.getElementsByName(site["3"])[0].value
```

But I cannot get it to go into a variable.

Thanks for looking,
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from `i`. Use a `for` loop since it fits the use case better than a `while` loop.

```
function formvalidation()
{
    var SiteNum= document.getElementsByName("sitesinput")[0].value,
        SitePhone;

    for(var i=1; i<=SiteNum; i++)
    {
        SitePhone = document.getElementsByName(site[i])[0].value;  
        alert(SitePhone);
    }
}
```

Also, JavaScript does not have block-level scoping, only function-level.

> I like this solution, however it wont work without the quotes (") i.e. if do everything the same, but put the name in myself, like ("site[1]") - it will work.

I see where you're headed now.

```
SitePhone = document.getElementsByName('site[' + i + ']')[0].value;
```

Comment: I like this solution, however it wont work without the quotes (") i.e. if do everything the same, but put the name in myself, like ("site[1]") - it will work. Any ideas.

Comment: Oh, so `site` isn't an array that contains names? See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the line

```
var SitePhone= document.getElementsByName(site['i'])[0].value;
```

for

```
var SitePhone= document.getElementsByName(site[i])[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting quotes around the i in the line

```
var SiteNum = document.getElementsByName(site['i'])[0].value
```

which is looking for the element keyed by the string 'i' instead of the value of the variable i.  Try removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 alert(document.getElementsByName(site[i])[0].value);
```